# Delayed slide after page load using CSS

Tags: css

I have a header inside of a DIV and I would like to add in a transition so it slides into view a couple of seconds after the pages loads.

Is this possible using CSS alone? I understand how transitions and transform works but they load in immediately and that isn't what I want.

Comment: That said, even with `transition-delay` you'll need some way to indicate to the CSS that something needs to change, so JS is almost essential. Luckily it's very minimal. This does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/r9HsJ/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for this to work, you'll need to place the CSS at the bottom of your Body content, to ensure the DOM has rendered as well as any other CSS/scripts run (e.g. the page has loaded). That said, the **better way** would be to listen to the document load event in Javascript, and apply a transitioning class at that point, as noted by [**Josiah**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1706605/josiah) in the comment to your question.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9HsJ/2/)

HTML

```
<div id="slidingContent"></div>
```

CSS

```
html,body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#slidingContent {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -120px;
    color: red;
    background-color: grey;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;    
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;   
    animation-name: slideIn;
    animation-duration: 0.3s;    
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;        
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
    0%   { margin-top: -120px;   }
    100% { margin-top: 0px;  }
}
@keyframes slideIn {
    0%   { margin-top: -120px;   }
    100% { margin-top: 0px;  }
}
```